# Assigning values to multiple keys without repeating the object name

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to assign values to multiple keys of an object without repeating the object name?

For example: We have this object created:

```
var obj = {
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0,
  "d": 0
}
```

What i want now is to assign values to some or all keys of this object which is already created(you would normally do it like this):

```
obj["a"] = yourValue;
obj["c"] = yourValue;
obj["d"] = yourValue;
```

but **without** repeating the object name as i did above.
Would there be a way to do such thing?

Comment: is `yourValue` only a primitive value?

Comment: I don't think you can get away from repeating `obj`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but without repeating the object name as i did above.

Object assign might come handy here

```
Object.assign(obj, { a: 0,b:0,c:0 });
```

---

```js
var obj = {
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0,
  "d": 0
}
Object.assign(obj, { a:1,b:0,c:1 });
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map the wanted keys with the values as object for an update with the wanted value.

```js
var object = { a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0 },
    value = 42,
    keys = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

Object.assign(object, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: value })));

console.log(object);
```

ES5

```js
var object = { a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0 },
    value = 42,
    keys = ['a', 'c', 'd'];

keys.forEach(function (k) {
    object[k] = value;
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0,
  "d": 0
};
yourvalue = 'test'
for(key in obj){
    obj[key] = yourvalue

}
```

A for-in loop will work for you. It loops trough all key entries and allows you to assign a value to it.

Comment: This assigns all values to youvalue.

Comment: Isn't this what he wanted? He used 'yourValue' in his example as well.

Comment: `What i want now is to assign values to some or all keys of this object which is already created`

Answer (score 0):

You can't go without iterating through the keys

```
var obj = {
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0,
  "d": 0
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
  obj[k] = yourValue;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be [with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) will help you, but

> Use of the with statement is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with the key values and then use a for loop.

```
var obj = {
  "a": 0,
  "b": 0,
  "c": 0,
  "d": 0
}
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  obj[arr[i]] = yourValue;
}
```